# gcc undefined reference to

Tags: gcc, undefined-reference

I'm running..

```
gcc -c -I/usr/vt/sample ttssample.c
gcc -L. -lttsapi ttssample.o -o ttsample
```

and I'm getting the following error...

```
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSFile':
ttssample.c:(.text+0x352): undefined reference to `TTSRequestFile'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSFileEx':
ttssample.c:(.text+0x5e0): undefined reference to `TTSRequestFileEx'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSBuffer':
ttssample.c:(.text+0x833): undefined reference to `_TTSRequestBuffer'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSBufferEx':
ttssample.c:(.text+0xabd): undefined reference to `_TTSRequestBufferEx'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSBuffering_cont':
ttssample.c:(.text+0xcbf): undefined reference to `_TTSRequestBuffer'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSBuffering_stop':
ttssample.c:(.text+0xf2d): undefined reference to `_TTSRequestBuffer'
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSBuffering_SSML':
ttssample.c:(.text+0x122b): undefined reference to `_TTSRequestBufferSSMLEx'   
ttssample.o: In function `_TTSStatus':
ttssample.c:(.text+0x157b): undefined reference to `TTSRequestStatus'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and TTSRequestFile is in the lib header but it has DllExport on the front of it which I'm wondering is the cause of my error?  Any help much appreciated.

```
DllExport int TTSRequestFile(char *szServer, int nPort, char *pText, int nTextLen, char *szSaveDir, char *szSaveFile, int nSpeakerID, int nVoiceFormat);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your link command is wrong. Libraries should be specified at the end of the command:

```
gcc ttssample.o -o ttsample -L. -lttsapi
```

Comment: Any idea as to why this would error running the executable?  error while loading shared libraries: -melf_x86_64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @JLB Because the library is not in a directory searched by default by the runtime loader. You would need to put the library in a searched directory (like /usr/local/lib), or export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the directory where the library resides (like LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/me/mylib"), or you would link your program using an rpath that points to the directory where the lib resides, or use the $ORIGIN feature of rpath to always look for the lib in a directory with a relative path to that of the executable. Search Google for "rpath origin" to find more about it.

Answer (score -1):

You could add preprocessor `ifdefines` around the `DllExport` call like so:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
// we are on windows

#elif defined __linux__
//we are on linux

#elif defined __APPLE__&__MACH__
// we are on mac

#endif // os specific
```

I added for the three platforms I have been compiling cross platform for. Do note that the keywords I use to recognize platforms may change, but the `_WIN32` one has been tested with windows 7 and 8.
I found these a year ago on sourceforge I think. I couldn't find the page right now, but I'll get back to you if I find it.

As I cannot yet comment on Nikos C's answer I'll comment it here: <del>Your link command is correct, I can of course not see you files, so I assume your paths are correct.</del> What is important is that `-l`'s need to be in correct order according to dependencies, but this is usually not a problem as far as I have experienced.